# How do I convert a chrono `DateTime<UTC>` instance to `DateTime<Local>`?

Tags: datetime, rust

My goal is to convert `utc` into `loc`:

```
use chrono::{Local, UTC, TimeZone};

let utc = chrono::UTC::now();
let loc = chrono::Local::now();

println!("{:?}", utc);
println!("{:?}", loc);

println!("{:?}", utc.with_timezone(&Local));
println!("{:?}", Local.from_utc_datetime(&utc.naive_local()));
```

... which produced the following output:

```
2015-02-26T16:22:27.873593Z
2015-02-26T17:22:27.873663+01:00
2015-02-26T15:22:27.873593+00:00
2015-02-26T15:22:27.873593+00:00
```

The `loc` time shown in the second row is what I want to see when converting `utc`.

How do I properly convert a `DateTime<UTC>` instance to `DateTime<Local>`?

#### Meta

I am using [chrono 0.2.2](https://crates.io/crates/chrono/0.2.2). In the [`DateTime.from_utc`](https://lifthrasiir.github.io/rust-chrono/chrono/datetime/struct.DateTime.html#method.from_utc) method it's even telling me I should use the `TimeZone` trait. However, I am missing something.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Oops, thank you for reporting. This is a bug and registered as the issue [#26](https://github.com/lifthrasiir/rust-chrono/issues/26). This should be fixed in Chrono 0.2.3.

Besides from the bug, `utc.with_timezone(&Local)` is indeed a correct way to convert to the local time. There is an important identity that `utc.with_timezone(&Local).with_timezone(&UTC)` should be equal to `utc` (except for the exceptional case, where the local time zone has been changed).

Comment: Thanks ! Would you adjust your answer to state that `with_timezone` is the way to do it to answer the question ? I'd be glad to greenlight it then. Cheers

Answer (score 19):

Starting with chrono 0.4.7 you can convert them between with using from trait in a simpler way:

```rust
use chrono::prelude::*;

fn main() {
    let utc = Utc::now();
    let local = Local::now();
    let converted: DateTime<Local> = DateTime::from(utc);
}
```