# How do I convert a chrono `DateTime<Local>` instance to `DateTime<Utc>`?

Tags: time, rust

There is a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28747694/how-do-i-convert-a-chrono-datetimeutc-instance-to-datetimelocal) asked before for the conversion in the other way`(Utc -> Local)`

---

I am trying to convert `Local` datetime into `Utc` time:

```rust
use chrono::{Local, UTC, TimeZone};

let utc = chrono::UTC::now(); // 2019-07-04 15:13:19.014970700 
let local = chrono::Local::now(); // 2019-07-04 17:13:19.014970700 +03:00
```

I am currently expecting some API like `local.to_utc()`. Maybe I can implement a `TryFrom` trait for such conversion.

How can I convert `Local` datetime to `Utc` datetime?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Chrono provides the [`TimeZone`](https://docs.rs/chrono/0.4.7/chrono/offset/trait.TimeZone.html) trait which has the method `from_local_datetime`.

```rust
use chrono::prelude::*;

fn main() {
    let local = Local::now();
    let utc = Utc
        .from_local_datetime(&local.naive_local())
        .single()
        .unwrap();

    dbg!(local.naive_local());
    dbg!(utc);
}
```

On my local machine it gives me:

```
[src/main.rs:10] local.naive_local() = 2019-07-04T14:25:15.093909965
[src/main.rs:11] utc = 2019-07-04T12:25:15.093909965Z
```

Answer (score 8):

As of chrono 0.4.7, this is now taken care of in a much cleaner way:

```
use chrono::prelude::*;

fn main() {
    let utc = Utc::now();
    let local = Local::now();
    let converted: DateTime<Utc> = DateTime::from(local);
    println!("{}\n{}", utc, converted);
}
```

This gives an output of:

```
2019-07-30 18:19:27.176827 UTC
2019-07-30 18:19:27.176836 UTC
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`chrono::DateTime::with_timezone`](https://docs.rs/chrono/latest/chrono/struct.DateTime.html#method.with_timezone) to convert any `DateTime` to another time zone.

It works for structs that implements [`TimeZone`](https://docs.rs/chrono/latest/chrono/offset/trait.TimeZone.html):
[`chrono::Local`](https://docs.rs/chrono/latest/chrono/offset/struct.Local.html), [`chrono::Utc`](https://docs.rs/chrono/latest/chrono/offset/struct.Utc.html). and [`chrono_tz::Tz`](https://docs.rs/chrono-tz/).

Example:

```rust
#![forbid(unsafe_code)]
use chrono::{DateTime, Local, Utc};

fn main() {
    let local_now: DateTime<Local> = Local::now();
    let utc_now: DateTime<Utc> = local_now.with_timezone(&Utc);
    println!("local = {}", local_now);
    println!("utc = {}", utc_now);
}
```

```
$ cargo run --bin example
local = 2021-07-01 15:45:26.251802 -07:00
utc = 2021-07-01 22:45:26.251802 UTC
```

Comment: If someone is interested in doing the other way around then just try `local_dt = DateTime::<Utc>::from_utc(utc_dt, Utc).with_timezone(&Local);`